# TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I am trying to parse a UTC timestamp that I pulled from a dict key and then subtract the results from the current time in UTC to compare them.

However, soon as I try to parse the date it results in a TypeError saying that it must be a string or character stream.

When I verify the Type, it shows that it is, in fact a string.

What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
def check_snapshot(snapshot_timestamp):
    # result = datetime.utcnow() - timestamp_formatted
    # minutes = result.total_seconds() / 60
    # hours = result.total_seconds() / 3600

    timestamp_formatted = dateparser.parse(snapshot_timestamp).astimezone(timezone('UTC'))

    print(type(snapshot_timestamp))
    print(now_utc)
    print(timestamp_formatted)

    if ((now_utc - timestamp_formatted).total_seconds() / 3600) > 24:
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

**Output:**

```
Checking backups (2022-06-02 12:08 PM)

<class 'str'>
2022-06-02 19:08:15.148078+00:00
2022-06-02 19:00:06+00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 303, in <module>
    main()
  File "debug.py", line 226, in main
    backup_status = check_snapshot(snapshot_timestamp)
  File "debug.py", line 83, in check_snapshot
    timestamp_formatted = dateparser.parse(snapshot_timestamp).astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
  File "/home/pythonuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pythonuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 646, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pythonuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 725, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)         # Splits the timestr into tokens
  File "/home/pythonuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 207, in split
    return list(cls(s))
  File "/home/pythonuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Parser must be a string or character stream, not '
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not NoneType
```

Comment: Did you try reproducing it with a minimal example? Literally, just `return dateparser.parse(snapshot_timestamp)` and see if it works?

Comment: @agarie thanks for the suggestion - I just tried that however it returns the exact same error.

Comment: Answering your question, you're passing `None` in a place where that is rejected. Also, you should rather ask yourself why you do that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not sure I follow - when I output the Type it shows that it's a string. When I print the variable it shows that it's not empty. I apologize if I'm missing something obvious - Python is not my strong suit.

Comment: Well, it's not directly in your code, it's in _parser.py line 75. That said, no, it's not obvious. So, for a start, extract a [mcve] from your code. If you didn't find the error yourself, you could include it in your question at least.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks - I'm using the python.dateutils so the error is stemming from there. That said, I took your suggestion to try and simplify the problem and manually copied the output into a new string e.g. test = '2022-06-02T20:00:06Z' - from here I was able to deduce that the parser returned without error and so there must be something extra that is being attached to my original data that the parser does not expect. Thank you for helping me narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the root cause thanks to @UlrichEckhardt's comment.

I used the **get** method to pull the key value from the dict (to avoid throwing a key error):

```
last = repository['status'].get('lastBackupTime')
```

However, it turns out that built-in methods return a None value.

In hindsight, this is not the best method to use because it can suppress other issues such as this one.

I have not been practicing Python for too long so I appreciate all the help.

Thank you,